# I hope you are right/you to be right

Tags: infinitives

Why is

> I hope you **are** right

written in that way and not

> I hope you **to be** right

Comment: "I hope you are right" is the common form of "I hope that you are right." Isn't it interesting that *we do say,* **"I want you to be right,"** when we are at once doubtful and hopeful that the more optimistic point of view is correct?

Comment: @MarkHubbard Weird. I thought it was used as I wrote it.

Answer (score 1):

Up to now I haven't seen the verb construction to hope + noun + to-infinitive. The normal constructions are to hope + that-clause or + to-infinitive.

See Oald: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/hope_1

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct structure of the sentence. *"I hope you are right"* is grammatically correct. Consider these sentences :

> 1. **I want you to be right.**
> 2. **I wish you were right.**

These sentences are extensively used in English.

Comment: But why? What's the difference between the verbs 'want' and 'hope' that the sentence structure is different?

Comment: -1 *I wish you **are** right* isn't something native speakers say. It's either *I wish you **were** right* or non-standard / uneducated / dialectal *I wish you **was** right*.